# Wrapper for async handlers in Express with custom request properties

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, asynchronous, promise

As demonstrated on https://strongloop.github.io/strongloop.com/strongblog/async-error-handling-expressjs-es7-promises-generators/#using-es7-asyncawait, I wanted to use a wrapper for all my async Express handlers to catch any errors happening there, but in a typed version for TypeScript.

I came up with this: (`wrap.ts`)

```
import { NextFunction, RequestHandler, Response, Request } from 'express';

type AsyncRequestHandler = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<any>;

/**
 * Catches errors and passes them to the next callback
 * @param handler Async express request handler/middleware potentially throwing errors
 * @returns Async express request handler with error handling
 */
export default (handler: AsyncRequestHandler): RequestHandler => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    return handler(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
};
```

I want to build a REST API with some endpoints like `PUT /users/:userId` and `DELETE /users/:userId`. For convenience, I don't want to query the specific user with the ID `userId` from the database in every handler and instead store it in `req` using a middleware. That means I have to use a modified `Request` interface for the handler definition adding a `user` property, e.g. `UserRequest`.

```
import express, { Request } from 'express';
import wrap from './wrap';

const app = express();

app.use('/users/:userId', wrap(async (req, res, next) => {
  // set req.user ...
}));

export interface UserRequest extends Request {
  user: User;
}

app.put('/users/:userId', wrap(async (req: UserRequest, res) => {
  // do something with req.user ...
}));

// ...
```

This would be possible when not using `wrap`, but not with this type definition of `wrap`. The TypeScript compiler produces the following error:

```
Argument of type '(req: UserRequest, res: Response) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AsyncRequestHandler'.
  Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
    Type 'Request' is not assignable to type 'UserRequest'.
      Property 'user' is missing in type 'Request'.
```

What is the "TypeScript way" to accomplish this?

Comment: I guess you will have to make `wrap` generic over the `Request` type

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a hint how this works?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: So that you'd use `wrap<UserRequest>(async (req, res) => { … req.user …`

Comment: Okay, I see, thanks.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce the error is to turn on `strictFunctionTypes`, and then I get the error on the argument to `app.put` even if I don't call `wrap`.  If I make `wrap` generic, then instead of getting the error on the argument to `wrap`, I get it when the wrapped handler is passed to `app.put`.  If you use `strictFunctionTypes`, you'll have to reconcile the difference between `UserRequest` and `Request` at some point.  For example, you could use a separate wrapper function that casts a handler that takes a `UserRequest` to one that takes a `Request`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that I have enabled the `strict` compiler option. And you are right; I somehow didn't realize that this happens without `wrap` as well.
Thanks for your suggestion. I ended up just extending the `express.Request` interface, which is not perfect but at least its a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow didn't realize that the issue appears without `wrap` as well (as long as the `strict` compiler option is enabled). My solution was to extend the `express.Request` interface.